# Querying a Kinetic.Spline for a parameterized (t) value along it's length

Tags: kineticjs

Is there a way to get an x,y value for a normalized 0 to 1 t value out of a KineticJS.Spline class?

For instance, if I'm interested in drawing circles on top of the spline at a constant interval.

If not, is there a good alternative JS library for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure...

You can get the starting point of the Kinetic.Spline by calling mySpline.getPoints().

You can get the curve definitions for a spline by calling the internal mySpline.getTensionPoints().

- The first curve definition is a quadratic curve (controlX, controlY, endX, endY)
- The rest of the curve defs are cubic curves. (control1X, control1Y, control2X, control2Y, endX, 
  endY);

Armed with this info, you can calculate any X/Y at interval T on each curve.

The way you framed your question indicates you already have the 2 formulas to calculate X/Y at interval T for quad and cubic curves.

Here is the equation to plot a quadratic curve at interval T:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// plot Quadratic Curve
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
function getQuadraticBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt,endPt,T) {
    var x = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.x + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.x + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.x; 
    var y = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.y + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.y + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.y; 
    return( {x:x,y:y} );
}
```

Here is the equation to plot a cubic Bezier curve at interval T:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
// plot Cubic Bezier Curve
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
function getCubicBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt1,controlPt2,endPt,T){
    var x=CubicN(T,startPt.x,controlPt1.x,controlPt2.x,endPt.x);
    var y=CubicN(T,startPt.y,controlPt1.y,controlPt2.y,endPt.y);
    return({x:x,y:y});
}

// cubic helper formula at T
function CubicN(T, a,b,c,d) {
    var t2 = T * T;
    var t3 = t2 * T;
    return a + (-a * 3 + T * (3 * a - a * T)) * T
    + (3 * b + T * (-6 * b + b * 3 * T)) * T
    + (c * 3 - c * 3 * T) * t2
    + d * t3;
}
```

If you want to peek at the spline internals, they are in the line.js source file:

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/shapes/Line.js

**[ Update: Ouch! -- KineticJS has replaced .getTensionPoints  with .allPoints ]**

The mySpline.getTensionPoints method has been replace by mySpline.allPoints.

You can get the starting point of the Kinetic.Spline by calling mySpline.getPoints().

You can get the curve definitions for a spline by calling the internal mySpline.allPoints

```
var curvePoints=mySpline.allPoints;
```

Now the points are JS point objects in the form {x:,y:}.

- The first curve definition is a quadratic curve: {x:controlX, y:controlY}, {x:endX, y:endY}
- The rest of the curve defs are cubic curves: {x:control1X, y:control1Y}, {x:control2X, y:control2Y}, {x:endX, y:endY}

Comment: That would be great if you could post them, I'm not actually that smart :)  What I'm actually trying to do is plot a dot traveling along a straight line and a spline at the same time by normalizing each.

Comment: I added the curve equations to my answer.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hmm... so, when I try to call to call mySpline.getTensionPoints(), I get the Object #<Object> has no method 'getTensionPoints'.  I only see it has getTension() in Dev Tools, but thats returns the scaler you pass in.  I'm trying to read through the source, but my knowledge of patterns is sketchy.  if var s = new Kinetic.Spline(...), how can I get to the tension points?  Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Ouch! You know...I like KineticJS but it's hard to keep up with their numerous new versions.  So in the this version, KineticJS has replaced .getTensionPoints()  with the mySpline.allPoints property.  I have added to may answer to describe the change.  Sorry that my info was outdated--I was going from memory.